# Will automation emancipate us from labour?

Tags: marx, philosophy-of-economics, arendt

In the *The Human Condition*, Arendt writes:

> The danger that the modern age's emancipation of labour will not only fail to usher in an age of freedom for all but will result, on the contrary, in forcing all mankind for the first time under the yoke of neccessity, was already clearly perceived by Marx when he insisted that the aim of a revolution could not possibly be the already-accomplished emancipation of the labouring classes, but must consist of the emancipation of man from labour.

And then:

> At first glance, this aim seems utopian, and the only strictly utopian element in Marx's teachings. Emancipation from labour, in Marx's own terms, is emancipation from neccessity...Yet, the developments of the last decade, and especially the possibilities opened up by automation, give us reason to wonder whether the utopia of yesterday will not turn into the reality of tommorrow.

Given, that Arendt wrote this over fifty years ago and in passing, and given the accelerated and accelerating pace of technological change where all manner of automations have become distinct possibilities has anyone seriously explored how this ties in (or not) with Marxs prediction and how likely it will lift the yoke of neccessity that is labouring (as opposed to work)?

Comment: Another word for "emancipation from labor" is unemployment. How will we eat? Will there be programmers making millions and everyone else living on the street? San Francisco is on the way there already. If labor becomes obsolete, we'll need a new economic model.

Comment: @user4894: sure, if there is no labour then we will have mass employment, and some other means of dividing the social product will be required - ie a new economic model - what this will be is anyone's guess; Marx didn't guess one, he simply asserted that at some point a new model will be required. I've worked as a programmer, and I can't say its worth millions as labour qua labour; but obviously it's a function of how it's fits in the modern economy.

Comment: Reminds me of Keynes's 15 hour work week: https://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/economics/keynes/1930/our-grandchildren.htm

Comment: Both did not anticipate the movement of 'labour' (as used in economic theory) into supply of services instead of production. This pretty much ruined the whole idea behind an *emancipation of man from labour*. I think as the very concept of labour of both authors here is tied to the capitalistic/economic concept, it would be simply false to destinguish it from 'work', as long as it's been paid.

Comment: @klocking: I agree with most of what you say, apart from your last sentence, Arendts notion of work is a technical term of hers, and doesn't really correspond to Marxs, it has a different orientation.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking  This is a sophisticated way of saying that even Arendt (a woman) basically did not realize women had desires of their own.  If the half of economics dominated by men is reduced, it will be made up by the half of economics dominated by women.  But that half of the economics was largely "unpaid" and maintained through the implicit transfer of male wealth to family usage.

Comment: @user4894: there seems to be people discussing it already - like this book on the [future of the professions](http://www.susskind.com/) where they're talking about deconstructing the 'grand bargain' that stabilised the position of the middle classes aka the professions; I'm also guessing that this is probably one of the motivations behind [basic income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_income) too...

Comment: @jobermark: but it ought to be pointed out that doubling the labour market , all other factors being equal, will reduce wages.

Comment: @MoziburUllah  Of course, but we didn't double the labor market, we included unpaid labor upon which the market's valuation was already unconsciously dependent.  And it wasn't doubling, because half or more of the work of **lower-class** women was already employment.  As we folded that unaccounted work in, we should have been **removing other work** -- but gender equality was approached from one front only, and basically against the advice of lower-class women.  As it was addressed, employers netted a massive unearned gain, and workers are now suffering.

Comment: @user4894, well, people say social welfare will be enough for that. But I disagree with this. We'll need somehow limit amount of property one can have.

Comment: @rus9384 Limit the amount of property one can have? Who decides? What happens to the excess? Sounds like socialism. Should the whole world become Venezuela?

Comment: @user4894, well, maybe socialism. Money have been invented with the purpose of justice, but became a tool of injustice.

Comment: @user4894: how about the people and their representatives - isn't this what democracy is about? The excess gets redistributed, it's what's called redistributive justice;  social democracy has been part of European politics for some time now - and no-one is saying that Europe does not do well.

Comment: As I said, welfare won't be enough. Welfare money must be taken from someone. Therefore, it leads to socialistic structure (well, not everyone must be equal in income, but it should be limited - maybe by some function depending on earnings, not merely a constant).

Comment: @user4894: Do you happen to know how much 'welfare' was paid out to financial institutions over the last decade, I mean since the crash?

Comment: Lol, that's not user4894, but Ok. Much less then will be needed. If 90% of people don't work (well, what even will be considered as work?) and don't have jobs, then who will be the consumers? As I predict in my answer, corporations won't be interested in automation, because then there won't be consumers (that's where the threshold appears). Not only that will not increase their income, it will decrease it, since their money will be taken for the welfare.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Not following your "what aboutism" question. I'm not defending corrupt corporate cronyism.

Comment: @user4984: ok, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

What you asked is more of a question about the nature of economics, and since I am decently versed in that as well, here you go with the hybrid answer:

The same was said about the washing machine, printing press, irrigation, the cotton gin, and a myriad of other technologies. The short answer is: While technology provides the opportunity to become more productive it does not eliminate the need for us to contribute value. Real money is based on the value you create for others. When you do something that makes others more productive either though tool, method, or personal labor you are creating a profit. In a healthy free society this can be exchanged to provide a win-win scenario.

Now, this does mean that people will possibly lose their jobs just as buggy whip makers did which is a GOOD THING IMHO since we have no need for those.  People not needing to do things like carry buckets of water is an improvement to civilization. This leaves them to pursue other ventures where they can produce additional value to others. Some displaced people also go and work on improving the new technology too to make it better. Some people out because they are unable to adapt and they go the way of the dodo bird. No one want's to see people suffer, yet people that are unwilling to face reality and adapt to the changes of nature around them are just as likely to be wiped out by a famine as they are a change in the market. I pity them for what they do to themselves yet have no guilt at watching them ruin their lives; It is like a mad man yelling at a tornado to get off his lawn.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom, so, you'd prefer to be a hunter in hunter-gatherer society and die at 30 being eaten by some animal?

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom, that's you who started to be a strawman. You connected two independent things together - carrying buckets and jobs. Job itself is a foundation of capitalism. Regarding economy - that's capitalist economy you refer to. You say automation is awful, while that's capitalism what is awful.

Answer (score 1):

Western thought boils down to dedication to ownership - copyrights, patents, fences, etc.  More broadly, human behavior is not unlike other mammals.  Dogs sniff one anothers butts, just as humans do.  Any media executive knows that what people subscribe to is dirty laundry, sex, and violence.  Women know men respond to the display of sexuality.  Men know women respond to financial wealth.  This behavior is rooted in what is the essence of mammals - reproduction with a desirable mate.

So, how is automation ever going to free man from his essence - desire?  I suppose it depends on what culture you are speaking of.  In the West, even if all essential labor is automated, the automation will be owned by someone.  In many ways, "work" is a means to reproduction (copulation); a means to differentiate yourself from the many.

The scary part of this automation is already evident vis-à-vis character assasination.  Mob mentality exists and we are all sinners, all do wrong, and will do wrong again.  Automation gets to a point where all wrongs are recorded and published.  Then what?  The Kübler-Ross model?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Arendt posits this as a hope; but in her essay she's also critical about this possible emancipation through accelerating technology, in a different line from yours.

Comment: Mob mentality is real for sure on the net.

Comment: I take it though, she's talking about an emancipation from labour, and not from ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a review](https://www.lrb.co.uk/v38/n13/owen-hatherley/one-click-at-a-time) of two major books that deal with current trends in automation from a Marxist perspective. These books are *[PostCapitalism: A Guide to Our Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostCapitalism:_A_Guide_to_our_Future)* by Paul Mason and *[Inventing the Future: Postcapitalism and a World without Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inventing_the_Future:_Postcapitalism_and_a_World_Without_Work)* by Nick Srnicek and Alex Williams. A key point raised by both of these works is that the consequences of automation will depend on whether they are accompanied by a universal [basic income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_income).

Comment: +1: it's great to see an answer that actually references something.

Answer (score 0):

> Will automation emancipate us from labour?

Depends on the definition of labour. There, indeed, are people who like some kind of non-intellectual labour. There are people who don't like it. Intellectual labour is - arts, science and philosophy. Yes, mere translation of algorithm from human language to programming language is not really intellectual. But development of new algorithms is intellectual labour.

Of course, the word *emancipate* means those who don't want X, won't need to do it in order to fulfill their desires.

So, why have I started to talk about intellectual labour? As you may think, among those people who do intellectual labour, much higher percentage do it because they want to do it, as opposed to those who do physical labour. Latter majorly do it *only* to have money, which on their turn, allows people to fulfill their desires. If they were not be in need for money, they would not do it. While artists, scientists and philosophers still would exist and do arts, science and philosophy.

This means that non-intellectual labour is majorly seen as undesirable and should be automated. People strived for this, and do it now. Of course, large corporations, as I see it, do it partially because it allows to get money faster. But that does not negate the fact that people want to get more by spending less.

So, there are a few prognoses possible.

## Prognosis 1.

Automation reaches the threshold when further automation is unprofitable for large companies, from the position of currency. So, automation stops. And no emancipation from labour.

## Prognosis 2.

This prognosis is really pessimistic one. As we know, money have only instrumental value. When there are only a little money, their value is survival and purchase of some desirable goods and services. But when there are a lot of money, their value turns to hard power. Power itself already can be seen by some people as having intrisic value. And then those people would prefer to have robots and other devices, while depriving others. Just because it allows having more power, which is seen as having intrisic value.

But as I said, it is pessimistic one, if really many people see power as intrisically valuable and not merely instrumentally.

## Prognosis 3.

As I said in prognosis 1, there is a threshold when further automation is unprofitable. In the optimistic case people will change current social structure by better one. By current I mean the one that offers only money as stimulus for labour (and automation itself is labour). By better I mean one that is better suited for it's purpose - emancipation from labour. In either case, it won't be capitalistic anymore.

---

So, as you can see, it won't necessarily result in emancipation from labour, but it is surely possible. Also, I should note that automation of non-intellectual labour is desirable, whatever the consequences people are seeing.

E.g. @jobermark wrote

> because the machines might need to be self-aware

Are the persons, who like non-intellectual labour, as I said in the start of my post, dangerous? I don't think so. It would not be better to create people who like non-intellectual labour (take "Brave New World" for example) than to create machines doing it.

> because disaster would take them off-line and culture would not pass down the ability to recreate them

There are many disasters that would take humanity "off-line" and machines surely can help mitigate or totally prevent them.

> because humans without purpose lose track of sanity

This depends on the definition of sanity. There surely are people who would incessantly use drugs or will just be so bored that they'd commit a suicide. But majority of people wants automation not for these purposes.

I don't see any problems why should automation be banned.

Answer (score 0):

It depends largely on who owns the automation, for it is the owners who are the primary beneficiaries of automation. If the automation is collectively owned, the collective will benefit. Otherwise, the collective may be simply left to starve outside fortress walls.